# Using Count to find the number of occurrences

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Let's say I have a table with the following values.

```
Ford
Ford
Ford
Honda
Chevy
Honda
Honda
Chevy
```

So I want to construct the following output.

```
Ford   3
Honda  3
Chevy  2
```

It just takes the count of each element in the column.

I'm having an issue listing the unique columns.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

I've messed around with `UNIQUE` and `DISTINCT`, but I'm not able to
get the list of values on the left.

Comment: I'll give you a hint: group by is what will group like rows by a column. select count(*) from table group by car_type should get you there.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
select car_make, count(*) from cars
group by car_makes
```

Answer (score 5):

```
select car_made, count(*) as occurrences
from cars
group by car_made
order by occurrences desc, car_made
```

Answer (score 2):

SELECT ... GROUP BY

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

For example:
`SELECT CarName, COUNT(CarName) AS CarCount FROM tbl GROUP BY CarName`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works for you!!

```
SELECT car_brand, COUNT(id) from cars
GROUP BY car_brand
```

> COUNT(id) with InnoDB is faster than COUNT(*) because InnoDB doesn't cache the row count.