# FIltering SQL column by number of occurrences

Tags: mysql

This is a follow-up to a question [already asked and answered here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654978/using-count-to-find-the-number-of-occurrences#)

Basically, for a table like this

```
Ford
Ford
Ford
Honda
Chevy
Honda
Honda
Chevy
```

If an output with the number of occurrences is desired, like so:

```
Ford   3
Honda  3
Chevy  2
```

The query is:

```
select car_made, count(*) from cars
group by car_made
```

---

Now, what I want is for the output to show only those values where the count is greater than 2. So, desired output:

```
Ford   3
Honda  3
```

How do I write the query for that?

I tried

```
select car_made, count(*) as carcount 
from cars
where carcount>2
group by car_made
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: i assume you need to know about `distinct` command...

Comment: @Reborn: `Group by` already assumes `distinct` unless `select all` is specified. But how does that help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use HAVING clause.

```
    select car_made, count(*) as carcount 
     from cars
    group by car_made
   having count(*) > 2
```

Comment: This is right, any filter you want to do over a group by needs to be done with having instead of where.